# python find the nearest row to a data with a certain label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

Type:  Volume:

Q     10

Q     20

T     NA

Q     10

T     NA

T     NA

Q     10

....

and when every I got type 'T' at row[i], I want to find the correspond value of Q[i-1] - Q[i+1] (i.e. the Q values that are closed to T, above and below T)

```
l = len(table)
dMidP = np.zeros((l,1))
check = np.zeros((l,1))
MidPrice = table['MidPrice']
Type = table['Type']
for i in range(2,l-1):
    if Type[i] == 'Quote':
        dMidP[i] = np.log(MidPrice[i])-np.log(MidPrice[i-1])
        check[i] = 0

    elif Type[i] == 'Trade' and Type[i+1] == 'Trade' :
        dMidP[i] = np.log(MidPrice[i+2])- np.log(MidPrice[i-1])
        check[i] = 2


    elif Type[i] == 'Trade' and Type[i-1] == 'Trade' :
        dMidP[i] = np.log(MidPrice[i+1])- np.log(MidPrice[i-2])
        check[i] = 2   

    else : 
        dMidP[i] = np.log(MidPrice[i+1])- np.log(MidPrice[i-1])
        check[i] = 1
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to find the nearest Q values to T (above T and below T)

Comment: What is your expected result from this sample dataset?

Comment: I want to set T value as the sum of the nearest two Q values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I we can do this so to create a couple a temp columns using ffill() and bfill() then subtract those columns to fillna.

```
df.assign(Volume=df.assign(fnaf=df.Volume.ffill(), fnab=df.Volume.bfill())
  .eval('Vnew = fnaf - fnab', inplace=False)
  .pipe(lambda x: x.Volume.fillna(x.Vnew)))
```

Output:

```
  Type  Volume
0    Q    10.0
1    Q    20.0
2    T    10.0
3    Q    10.0
4    T     0.0
5    T     0.0
6    Q    10.0
```

Edit adding log function:

```
df.assign(Volume=df.assign(fnaf=np.log(df.Volume.ffill()), fnab=np.log(df.Volume.bfill()))
  .eval('Vnew = fnaf - fnab', inplace=False)
  .pipe(lambda x: x.Volume.fillna(x.Vnew)))
```

Comment: thank you very much for this! really helps a lot! btw may I ask how can I obtain log difference (i.e log(fnaf)-log(fnab)) instead of fnaf-fnab?

Comment: Also when I use this code, I keep getting 0 for T no matter the values of Qs

Comment: As you can see from the data here, the first is 10 but the second and third T's are 0 because Q before equals to Q afterwards.  Maybe you could update the problem with the data that causes you isssue.